# Nextion no response

Tags: arduino, nextion

Hello I have been making a project with arduino and nextion but when I run it the nextion does not respond like it turns on and works like normal but it does not show any change to the screen the arduino controls it.

The code of arduino:

```
#include <Nextion.h>

NexText tb = NexText(0,4,"tb");
NexPicture eye = NexPicture(0,3,"eye");

void setup() {
  eye.setPic (6);
  tb.setText ("loading");
  delay(1000);
  eye.setPic (1);
  tb.setText ("loaded");
  delay(500);
  tb.setText ("HelloWorld");
}

void loop() {
  eye.setPic (1);
  delay(1000);
  eye.setPic (6);
  delay(500);
}
```

I copied some of the code from the internet but it looks like somthing is wrong.

1. Disconnected and reconnected the nextion
2. Reseted the arduino multiple times
3. Checked and compiled the arduino code
4. Checked any errors in nextion

None of this works so please help ᓚᘏᗢ

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is missing a setup call to `nexInit()`.  Check [these release notes](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/nextion-v0-9-0-library-with-working-gui-events/596412) or the [homepage](https://nextion.tech/faq-items/iteadlib-arduino-nextion-library/).

Comment: Btw I fixed the problem of the response issue.